# How to know which address space a buffer head is mapped to?

Tags: c, memory-management, ext4, journaling

In the **jbd2** source code, any modification in the File System is mapped into a `handle_t` structure (per process) that later is used to map the `buffer_head` to the `transaction_t` which this handle is going to be part of.

As far as I could understand, when a modification to a given `buffer_head` is needed, then a call to `do_get_write_access()` is going to map this `buffer_head` to the transaction that the `handle_t` is being part of.
However, when this `handle_t` is used to map the `buffer_head` to the `transaction_t`, the reciprocal mapping is lost, that is, I cannot track back to which `handle_t` this `buffer_head` belonged.

The thing is that, during the `jbd2_journal_commit_transaction()` (***commit phase 2b*** in commit function) I want to find a way to walk through these `buffer_heads` and be able to classify them if they are related to an ***inode***, or to a ***metadata***, or to a ***inode bitmap block***, or an ***data bitmap block***, for example. Furthermore, at this point in the source code, the `buffer_heads` seems to be opaque, where they are simply sent to the storage.

**UPDATE 1:**

What I have tried so far was this, in the `jbd2_journal_commit_transaction()` function, in the ***commit phase 2b***.

```
struct journal_head *jh;
...
jh = commit_transaction->t_buffers;
if(jh->b_jlist == BJ_Metadata) {
    struct buffer_head *bh_p = NULL;
    bh_p = jh2bh(jh);
    if(!bh_p) printk(KERN_DEBUG "Null ptr in bh_p\n");
    else {
        struct address_space *as_p = NULL;
        if((as_p = bh_p->b_assoc_map) == NULL)
            printk(KERN_DEBUG "Null ptr in as_p\n");
        else {
            struct inode *i_p = NULL;
            if(i_p) printk(KERN_DEBUG "Inode is %lu\n", i_p->i_ino);
        }
    }
}
```

It is not working, it is giving NULL ptr in the `as_p`, that is, there is no `b_assoc_map` set for this `buffer_head`. But, I have no idea what is the `b_assoc_map`.

**UPDATE 2:**

I am trying to get the information from the `handle_t` structure at `ext4_mark_iloc_dirty`. `handle_t->h_type` has the information I need. However, when I try to compare this value, a NULL pointer is causing a kernel warning. I thought this structure is unique per process, but seems like it is having some race condition, I don't know clearly yet.

Comment: A bit more code would help comprehend the problem.

Comment: That is the thing, I didn't change anything in the *jbd2* source code, so there is no way to put any code here. Up to now I was investigating and trying to find a way to track back these relationships between `buffer_head` and `handle_t`.

Comment: Well, I added some code that I tried, but I don't think it is quite useful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After looking through all the source code path related to this issue, I conclude that there is no way to do it without changing anything.

Basically, the `handle_t` structure has the information about the transaction. Later, when some modification is going to be done in a given `buffer_head`, the `jbd2_journal_get_write_access(handle, bh)` is called to get the write access to the specified buffer.

Inside `jbd2_journal_get_write_access` the `journal_head` structure is created, and then it is going to point to this `buffer_head`, however, at this point there is no relation between `handle_t`.

Next step, after returning from `jbd2_journal_add_journal_head`, a call to `do_get_write_access(handle, bh)` is made, and here the `journal_head` is initialized with the information passed by the `handle_t`.

After this step, where the `handle_t` is used to initialize the `journal_head`, then the `handle_t` is not necessary anymore.

Up to here, everything is initialized, now we can move to the commit point.

In `jbd2_journal_commit_transaction`, at ***commit phase 2b*** the `buffer_heads` belonging to the committing transaction are going to be iterated, and committed.

Because the only information attached to the `buffer_head` is the `journal_head`, and the `journal_head` does not contain the necessary information to distinguish what kind of `buffer_head` is it, then I conclude that it is not possible to reach what I want without modifying the source code.

My solution was to add a new member to store the inode number in the `handle_t`, and also in `journal_head` structure. So, when the `do_get_write_access()` call is made, I can filter the operation like this:

```
if(handle->h_ino)
    jh->b_ino = handle->h_ino;
```

So, I had to modify `handle_t` to transport the inode number to `journal_head`, and at commit time I can get the required information that I want.